# How should I rewrite 我昨天卖了我的电脑给他 using 把 and 了?

Tags: grammar, phrase

The goal is to re-write the sentences using 把.

### Example 1

那个字，他写错了。

Rewrite: 他**把**那个字写错了。

### Example 2

你的学生证，你没有给我。

Rewrite: 你没有**把**你的学生证给我。

### Question

我昨天卖了我的电脑给他。

Rewrite: `?`

---

Should it be 我**把**我昨天卖了我的电脑给他? It seems like strange to say 了 in '天卖了我的'?

Comment: Is it your homework? This exercise requires you to study the two examples, and determine the function and placement of 把. You need to identify the subject, object and verb. Then figure out how 把 change their position. Simply show you the correct rewrite will not help your study.

Comment: @TangHo Yes, you are right. I think i understand where to put 把. I would assume the answer is 我把我昨天买的电脑给她。Although ... I am not sure about the suggestion above, is that correc,t using the 了 in '天卖了我的' again? It feels like a strange structure to me?

Comment: The main verb in this sentence is not 给(give). It is 卖了 (sold), and the whole verb phrase is "卖了给他" (sold to him)

Comment: @TangHo Ah, thank you. I now understand the original sentence better. :) I think I couldn't interpret it before. I couldn't really grasp the meaning, was reading it wrong before. :D

Comment: So then the correct answer is 我昨天把我的电脑卖给他了。 ：）

Comment: or 我昨天把我的电脑卖了给他

Comment: "了"  in "我昨天把我的电脑卖给他了" is a final particle

Comment: "了"  in "我昨天把我的电脑卖了给他 is a verb particle that indicates the verb 卖 is completed. Both sentences are valid. but the verb is "卖了"  so the correct answer is the one I gave

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: One more thing, 我昨天... or  昨天我... are both valid

Comment: ```我昨天卖了我的电脑给他。``` -> ```我卖sth```. ```我把我昨天买的电脑给她``` -> ```我给sth```. So they are different, and, just put ```把``` before "sth". (Or you would like a proper answer?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

把 is used to denote thing have been done something to.

To use 把.

First, find out what exactly is the thing have been done something to. In your example, 我昨天賣了我的電腦給他. The thing(我的電腦) had been done something(賣了) to.

Second, put the thing after 把. 把我的電腦

Third, try to refill the semantics you have lost. 把我的電腦 is not complete to express what original sentence(我昨天賣了我的電腦給他) means. 我把我的電腦 我昨天把我的電腦 我昨天把我的電腦賣了 我昨天把我的電腦賣給了他.